Proving that a line through an interior point of a convex polygon intersects it in exactly two points
Suppose we have a convex polygon and a line that goes through an interior point (i.e. not containing an entire side or just a corner), I want to show that the line intersects the Polygon in exactly two points. I think it makes intuitively sense, since then the entire line must be contained in the polygon. However, my argument is then a bit fishy proceeding by contradiction, and assuming there are three points and something must be left and right of the line connecting these three points. I would like to produce a more rigorous proof.
The solution here is also not satisfying, since they say that for a finite line segment the points $A$ and $B$ which are the endpoints of the segment are boundary points, but do not consider what would happen if a third point is on the line segment and boundary.
I would appreciate any help!

what properties or theorems would you approve to use here?

I would like to just use the property convex or if there are simple to prove theorems with a reference, but I would prefer just the definition of a convex set

Why make us go to a link? Explain what points A and B are in the question body.

@coffeemath I have added the information

The segment excluding the two endpoints must lie entirely in the interior of the convex figure. So there is no way there's a third intersection of the line and the convex figure's boundary.

@Vim but why is that?

Suppose endpoints are $a,b\in\partial H$ where $H$ is the convex figure. Suppose that $c\in int(H)$ is one interior point that the line $ab$ passes through, which exists by the condition given. Choose an open ball $B(c)\subset int(H)$ centred at $c$. If you connect every point of $B(c)$ with $a$, these segments will form a cone shape, which lies entirely in $H$ by convexity, and you can see any $d\in(a,c)$ (the open segment excluding endpoints $a,c$) permits a tiny neighborhood that's entirely within the cone shape. Then argue similarly for the open arc $(c,b)$.

Just a little thing. I believe this is true even more generally, in the sense you can drop the word polygon for compact set.

on second thought i think it is ok to use a link as you did.

To flesh out my comment into an answer here: the only thing we need to prove is that the segment $[a,b]$ excluding the two endpoints $a,b$ must lie entirely in the interior of the convex figure $H$. Since the line $ab$ passes through at least one interior point, say $c\in int(H)$, we can choose a closed ball $\bar B_r(c)\subset int(H)$ centered at $c$ of radius $r$. Consider the set
$$K:=\bigcup_{x\in \bar B_r(c)}(a,x)$$
where $(x,y)$ denotes the "open segment" i.e. the segment connecting $x,y$ excluding the two endpoints. Since each $a,x\in H$, by the convexity of $H$ we have $(a,x)\subset H$. Therefore $K\subset H$. Intuitively, $K$ is a cone shape that peaks at $a$.
Now we investigate an arbitrarily chosen point $p\in (a,c)$. Suppose $p=a+\lambda (c-a),\lambda\in(0,1)$
Then for each $x\in\bar B_r(c)$, the point $y:=a + \lambda (x-a)\in K$, and we have $|y-p|=\lambda |x-c|\le \lambda r$. Running through each $x$, we see that the non-empty closed ball $\bar B_{\lambda r}(p)\subset K\subset H$, which establishes that $p\in int(H)$. Therefore $(a,c)\subset int(H)$. Argue similary for $(c,b)$, then we have $(a,b)\subset int(H)$.

Suppose $x$ is an interior point of a convex polygon $P$, and let $Q$ denote the union of $P$ and its interior, which is convex. For a given direction $v$, we look at $A_v = \{t > 0: x + tv \in Q\}$.
Then $A_v$ is
itself convex since $Q$ is, and if $a = \sup\{t: x + tv \in Q\}$ then $x + av$ is on the boundary of $P$ with the line segment
$[x, x + av]$ being contained in $Q$. The issue is whether or not some $c$ on $(x, x + av]$ other than $x + av$ can be on the boundary $P$. But any such $c$ can be written as $tx  + (1 - t)(x + av)$ for some $0 < t < 1$. Furthermore, since $x$ is an interior point of $P$ there is a ball $B$ centered at $x$ contained in $Q$. Then $c \in tB + (1 - t)(x + av)$, which is a ball centered at $x$ which must be contained in $Q$ by the convexity of $Q$. Thus $c$ is an interior point of $Q$ and not on the boundary.
So any line containing $x$ intersects $P$ in exactly two points; if $v$ is parallel to the line then one point will be the boundary point $a + tv$ above, and the other will be corresponding point for $-v$ in place of $v$.
